# question on a simple indexer (c#)

Tags: c#, .net

in the following indexer code block, why do we need:

```
public string this[int pos]
{
    get
    {
        return myData[pos];
    }
    set
    {
        myData[pos] = value;
    }
}
```

what exactly does "this" in this[int pos] do? Thanks

```
/// Indexer Code Block starts here
using System;

/// <summary>
///     A simple indexer example.
/// </summary>
class IntIndexer
{
    private string[] myData;

    public IntIndexer(int size)
    {
        myData = new string[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            myData[i] = "empty";
        }
    }

    public string this[int pos]
    {
        get
        {
            return myData[pos];
        }
        set
        {
            myData[pos] = value;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int size = 10;

        IntIndexer myInd = new IntIndexer(size);

        myInd[9] = "Some Value";
        myInd[3] = "Another Value";
        myInd[5] = "Any Value";

        Console.WriteLine("\nIndexer Output\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("myInd[{0}]: {1}", i, myInd[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anybody else smell homework? If it is...it should be tagged as such.

Comment: its not homework. im teaching myself C# through an online tutorial
http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson11.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From a c# syntax perspective:**

You need `this` because - how else would you declare it? Functionality on a class must have a name, or address, by which to reference it.

A method signature is:

```
[modifiers] [type]   [name]    (parameters)

public      string   GetString (Type myparam);
```

A property signature is:

```
[modifiers] [type]   [name]

public      string   MyString
```

A field signature is:

```
[modifiers] [type]   [name]

public      string   MyString
```

Since an indexer has no name, it would not make much sense to write:

```
public string [int pos]
```

So we use `this` to denote it's "name".

Comment: Indexers have a name - "Item", and that name is marked with the DefaultMemberAttribute by the compiler. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119814/-net-defaultmemberattribute-what-does-it-do

Comment: @Cameron that is at the IL level. My answer is at the c# syntax level - it could be MagicalIndexerKeyword[int pos] in c#. 'This' is what the language designers chose.

Answer (score 4):

It means that you can use the indexer on the object itself (like an array).

```
class Foo
{
    public string this[int i]
    {
        get { return someData[i]; }
        set { someData i = value; }
    }
}

// ... later in code

Foo f = new Foo( );
string s = f[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just marker for compiler to know that that property has indexer syntax.

In this case it enables myInd to use "array syntax" (e.g. myInd[9]).

Answer (score 0):

The 'this' keyword indicates that you are defining behavior that will be invoked when your class is accessed as if it was an array. Since your defining behavior for the class instance, use of the 'this' keyword in that context makes sense. You don't call myInd.indexer[], you call myInd[].

Answer (score 0):

It allows your class to behave in a similar manner to an array. In this case, your indexer is allowing you to reference myData transparently from outside the IntIndexer class.

If you didn't have the indexer declared, the following code would fail:

```
myInd[1] = "Something";
```

Answer (score 0):

The "this" in your case specifies that this property is the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464%28VS.71%29.aspx) for this class.  This is the syntax in C# to define an indexer on a class, so you can use it like:

```
myInd[9] = ...
```