# Identifying a custom indexer using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class with a custom indexer like so

```
public string this[VehicleProperty property]
{
  // Code
}
```

How can I identify the custom indexer in the results of typeof(MyClass).GetProperties()?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can also look for index parameters, using the the [PropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getindexparameters.aspx) method, if it returns more than 0 items, it's an indexed property:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(MyClass).GetProperties())
{
    if (pi.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0)
    {
       // Indexed property...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Look for the `DefaultMemberAttribute` defined at type level.

(This used to be `IndexerNameAttribute`, but they seem to have dropped it)

Comment: The `DefaultMemberAttribute` does not necessary reference an indexer, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1119949/1161635).

Comment: @Herman But if there is an indexer, then the `DefaultMemberAttribute` will refer to it, to the extent that you can't apply `DefaultMemberAttribute` to a class with an indexer.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Interesting, what happens if the class has more than one indexer?

Comment: @Herman I'm guessing since indexers in C# will always have the name `Item`, the compiler-generated `DefaultMemberAttribute` will point to `Item` without specifying which overload.

Answer (score 3):

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeof(System.Collections.ArrayList).GetProperties()) {

            System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[] parameterInfos = propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters();
            // then is indexer property
            if (parameterInfos.Length > 0) {
                System.Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name);
            }
        }


        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a known indexer you can use:

```
var prop = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("Item", new object[]{typeof(VehicleProperty)});
var value = prop.GetValue(classInstance, new object[]{ theVehicle });
```

or you can get the getter method of the indexer:

```
var getterMethod = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("get_Item", new object[]{typeof(VehicleProperty)});
var value = getterMethod.Invoke(classInstance, new object[]{ theVehicle });
```

if the class has only one indexer, you can omit the type:

```
var prop = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("Item", , BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

I've added this answer for the ones who google search led them here.

Comment: Note that only in C# will the indexer definitely be named `Item`.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one indexer, you can use this:

```
var indexer = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties().First(x => x.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0));
```

If there are multiple indexers, you can select the overload you want by supplying the arguments like this:

```
var args = new[] { typeof(int) };
var indexer = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties().First(x => x.GetIndexParameters().Select(y => y.ParameterType).SequenceEqual(args));
```

You can create a helper extension like this:

```
//Usage      
var indexer = typeof(MyClass).GetIndexer(typeof(VehicleProperty));
//Class
public static class TypeExtensions
{
  public static PropertyInfo GetIndexer(this Type type, params Type[] arguments) => type.GetProperties().First(x => x.GetIndexParameters().Select(y => y.ParameterType).SequenceEqual(arguments));
}
```