# Detect indexer from MethodInfo

Tags: c#, expression-trees, system.reflection

Given the following code:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>() {
    {"",""}
};
Expression<Func<string>> expr = () => dict[""];
```

`expr.Body` returns an instance of `MethodCallExpression`, whose `Method` property returns the `get__Item` `MethodInfo`.

There doesn't seem to be any information which I can use to detect that the method being called (`get__Item`) is the method underlying an indexer.

**How can I detect that a given `MethodInfo` refers to the method underlying an indexer?**

This is not a duplicate of [Indentifying a custom indexer using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347936/indentifying-a-custom-indexer-using-reflection-in-c-sharp), because (as noted in the title, the comments, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54027720/111794)) I don't have a `PropertyInfo`, only a `MethodInfo`; and the linked question is asking about identifying a specific `PropertyInfo` as the indexer.

I am trying to map expression trees to Roslyn `SyntaxNode`s, and the above expression tree should not be mapped as:

```
() => dict.Item("")
```

or:

```
() => dict.get__Item("")
```

but rather, as the original source code:

```
() => dict[""]
```

Comment: an indexer is a property.

Comment: `IsSpecialName` would tell you that it's not a normal method. Would that do or do you specifically need to know it's "indexeryness". I.e. what do you intend to do with the answer?

Comment: @DanielA.White and all I have is a `MethodInfo`, from which I need to somehow figure out that the original expression was (or could have been written) using an indexer.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Edited.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update: I can't delete this because it's the accepted answer. It worked for someone but I'd check out [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347936/identifying-a-custom-indexer-using-reflection-in-c-sharp).

You can determine which property (if any) is an indexer by inspecting the type. (You're looking at a method, not a property, but I'll get to that.)

From [the `DefaultMemberAttribute` reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.defaultmemberattribute?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Reflection.DefaultMemberAttribute);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2)

> The C# compiler emits the DefaultMemberAttribute on any type containing an indexer.

So the question becomes

- does the type on which the method is invoked have that attribute?
- is the method you're inspecting either the getter or setter for that
  property?

If the answer to both is "yes" then the method accesses an indexer property.

Here are a few functions. This isn't pretty. I'm not questioning whether or not your reason makes sense. I just found it interesting.

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions
{
    public static bool IsIndexerPropertyMethod(this MethodInfo method)
    {
        var declaringType = method.DeclaringType;
        if (declaringType is null) return false;
        var indexerProperty = GetIndexerProperty(method.DeclaringType);
        if (indexerProperty is null) return false;
        return method == indexerProperty.GetMethod || method == indexerProperty.SetMethod;
    }

    private static PropertyInfo GetIndexerProperty(this Type type)
    {
        var defaultPropertyAttribute = type.GetCustomAttributes<DefaultMemberAttribute>()
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (defaultPropertyAttribute is null) return null;
        return type.GetProperty(defaultPropertyAttribute.MemberName, 
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    }
}
```

These are not the most glorious unit tests, but I like to include them anyway.

```
[TestClass]
public class ReflectionExtensionTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void DetectsIndexer()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            {"",""}
        };
        Expression<Func<string>> expr = () => dict[""];
        var method = (expr.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method;
        Assert.IsTrue(method.IsIndexerPropertyMethod());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DetectsNotIndexer()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            {"",""}
        };
        Expression<Action<string, string>> expr = (s, s1) => dict.Add(s, s1);
        var method = (expr.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method;
        Assert.IsFalse(method.IsIndexerPropertyMethod());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DetectsRenamedIndexer()
    {
        var myClass = new ClassWithRenamedIndexer();
        Expression<Func<int>> expr = () => myClass[2];
        var method = (expr.Body as MethodCallExpression).Method;
        Assert.IsTrue(method.IsIndexerPropertyMethod());
    }

    class ClassWithRenamedIndexer
    {
        [IndexerName("blarg")]
        public int this[int index]    // Indexer declaration  
        {
            get { return 1; }
        }
    }
}
```