# C# Type as object with indexer

Tags: c#, indexer

Consider a situation:
I have a method which use DataRow:

```
public void MyMethod (DataRow input)
{
    DoSomething(input["Name1"]);
}
```

But now I have some another input types with indexer which I want to pass to this method. St like:

```
public void MyMethod (AnyTypeWithIndexer input)
{
    DoSomething(input["Name1"]);
}
```

But I haven't found anything like that. I tried IDictionary but it didn't work.
Is there any super type st like "Indexable" or anything with which I can replace the "AnyTypeWithIndexer"?

Note: I still need this method to pass the DataRow and also my custom class (which I want to implement).

Can anybody help?

Thanks.

Comment: You havent asked a question.  What is it you are trying to accomplish? Are you asking what type `AnyTypeWithIndexer` should be?  Are you asking what type `DoSomething` should take as a parameter?  Its extremely unclear

Comment: Edited. Better now?

Comment: There's no 'interface' behind [indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers) - you _could_ [use reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347936/identifying-a-custom-indexer-using-reflection-in-c-sharp) though.

Comment: Reflection is an option, but at this point I think just making method overloads would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dynamic` type, but you will need to be noticed about the disadvantages of `dynamic`, such as performance drawbacks because of DLR, and the fact that type safety should be on your shoulders

```
    public class WithIndexer
    {
        public int this[string key] => 42;
    }

    public static async Task Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> a = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        a.Add("meow", 41);

        Foo(a, "meow");
        Foo(new WithIndexer(), "key");
    }

    private static void Foo(dynamic indexed, string key)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(indexed[key]);
    }
```

Output:

```
41
42
```

Comment: Wow. Will it also pass a DataRow?

Comment: @xMichal, yes, see more about [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic)

Answer (score 5):

No, unfortunately, there is no interface that automatically applies to *"all classes with an indexer that takes a string argument and returns an object"*.

What you can do, however, is to create a "proxy class" that implements such an interface 
yourself:

```
public interface IStringToObjectIndexable
{
    object this[string index] { get; set; }
}

class DataRowWrapper : IStringToObjectIndexable
{
    private readonly DataRow row;

    public DataRowWrapper(DataRow row) => this.row = row;

    public object this[string index]
    {
        get => row[index];
        set => row[index] = value;
    }
}
```

MyMethod can now be declared as follows:

```
public void MyMethod(IStringToObjectIndexable input)
{
    DoSomething(input["Name1"]);
}

// Compatibility overload
public void MyMethod(DataRow input) => MyMethod(new DataRowWrapper(input));
```