# Assign direct value to object

Tags: vb.net, class, properties

I have several properties, for example

```
Public Property FIRSTNAME As New SQLString("FirstName", 50)
Public Property FULLNAME As New SQLString("Name", 50)
```

The SQLString object is defined as:

```
Public Class SQLString
    Property SQL_Column As String
    Property Limit As Integer
    Property Value As String

    Public Sub New(SQLcolumn As String, limit_ As Integer)
        SQL_Column = SQLcolumn
        Limit = limit_
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property SQL_value() As String
        Get
            Return "'" & clean(Value, Limit) & "'"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Notice that through this method, each of my properties (e.g. `FIRSTNAME`) is able to have several sub properties, which is necessary.

To access them, it's simply for example `FIRSTNAME.SQL_Column`.

This works, however what I would like is to also be able to store a value (e.g. string data type) on the `FIRSTNAME` property itself, which would make accessing it like:

```
Dim MyFirstName As String = FIRSTNAME
```

Rather than:

```
Dim MyFirstName As String = FIRSTNAME.Value
```

Which is what I currently have to do.
The only way I can see to do this is to have the SQLString object be set to string (or another data type) by default, like:

```
Public Class SQLString As String
```

Obviously the above code does not work, but I'm wondering if there is an equivalent that does?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default properties in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293215/default-properties-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 2):

The default access modifier to a property (ie: Public, Private, etc) is the most restrictive when no access modifier is provided. In SQLString class, since there is not a `Public` access modifier in front of the properties in the class, they are essentially `Private` and not accessible from outside of the class.

Adding the access modifier to the properties should fix the issue you see:

```
Public Property SQL_Column As String
Public Property Limit As Integer
Public Property Value As String
```

Please tell me the problem for the vote downs - here is a working .NET fiddle of the proposed code changes above (https://dotnetfiddle.net/96o8qm).

```
Imports System
Dim p as Person = new Person()
p.FIRSTNAME = new SQLString("Test", 1)
p.FIRSTNAME.Value = "Test Value"
Console.WriteLine("Person Value: {0}", p.FIRSTNAME.Value)

Public Class Person
    Public Property FIRSTNAME AS SQLString
End Class

Public Class SQLString
    Public Property SQL_Column As String
    Public Property Limit As Integer
    Public Property Value As String

    Public Sub New(SQLcolumn As String, limit_ As Integer)
        SQL_Column = SQLcolumn
        Limit = limit_
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property SQL_value() As String
        Get
            Return ""
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

This yields the output:

```
Person Value: Test Value
```

Comment: No, that does not fix the problem that I still need `FIRSTNAME.Value` rather than just `FIRSTNAME` to access the string s value.

Comment: Please help me understand what I a missing and the downvotes. The change I suggested allows you to do `FIRSTNAME.Value`. I provided a working .NET fiddle showing so - please let me know my misunderstanding so I can address any specific issue with my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I still need `FIRSTNAME` to access the value RATHER THAN `FIRSTNAME.Value`, as this code will be used hundreds of times throughout my project, and I want to avoid the `.Value`. Sorry, that was a mistake in my comment.

Comment: That makes sense with your intent, but I don't believe it is directly possible. What you describe is the "Default" keyword, but by nature, Default requires an index (ie: `FIRSTNAME(i)`) so that VB can differentiate between assigning the default property and the class itself (ie: `FIRSTNAME = new SQLString(...)`). There won't be a direct way to do something like that for your code. Best bet may be investing in Resharper or something like that to refactor all that code for you.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is quite simple; add a [CType widening operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz3wbx3x.aspx).

Example:

```
Public Class SQLString

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal s As SQLString) As String
        Return If((s Is Nothing), Nothing, s.Value)
    End Operator

    Public Property Value As String

End Class
```

Test:

```
Dim firstName As New SQLString() With {.Value = "Bjørn"}
Dim myName As String = firstName

Debug.WriteLine(myName)
```

Output *(immediate window)*:

> Bjørn

Comment: I tried something similar, but the issue I was still having is that then I was then not able to access the properties `Limit` and `SQL_Column` of (for example) FIRSTNAME.SQL_Column would not be accessible

Comment: Huh? Look at your question. `Dim MyFirstName As String` Here it's obvious that you only need a string value. Nothing else. But now you suddenly need all the other properties? Why not keep it as is?