# What is VB.net equivalent of this in inherited BaseCollection class?

Tags: vb.net, this, translate

I try to convert following C# code to VB.NET but I block on following code

```
public class StringCollection : CollectionBase
{
    public String this[int Index]
    {
        get
        {
            return (String)List[Index];
        }
    }
}
```

What is correct code for `public String this[int Index]` in VB.Net ?

Comment: [Declare and Call a Default Property in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-declare-and-call-a-default-property)

Comment: [Default properties in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/294405/14171304)

Answer (score 1):

That is an indexer in C#. That is implemented in VB using a default property, most often named `Item`. See the `List(Of T)` class as an example. It has an [`Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.item?view=net-8.0) property in VB but an indexer in C#.

That said, you really shouldn't be using `CollectionBase` this decade. That was provided as a base class for custom collections from .NET Framework 1.0. It effectively became obsolete in 2005 when generics were introduced with .NET Framework 2.0 and the [`Collection(Of T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1?view=net-8.0) class was introduced.